# How do I get to Townlong Steppes?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I got the quest `Beyond The Wall` from the Adventure Journal. It wants me to go to Townlong Steppes. I can't quite figure out how to get there. I went to Vale of Eternal Blossoms and ran west but there's a bigass wall covering the entire western border (or so it seems). How do I get there? Assume I've never been to any zone except Vale of Eternal Blossoms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get into Townlong Steppes via multiple routes, depending on your level and whether you're unlocked flying for Pandaria yet. It sounds like you haven't...

Townlong Steppes is accessed on foot via Kun-Lai Summit, through a gate in the wall in the western part of Kun-Lai Summit near Winter's Blossom:

[image: kun-lai summit]

If you can fly... well, go over the wall from Vale of Eternal Blossoms.